# Let $|z|=1, $ prove that $|z^2-3z+1|\leq 5$ ....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem :

Let $|z|=1, $ prove that $|z^2-3z+1|\leq 5$

My approach :

Let $z = x +iy$

$ \Rightarrow (x^2+y^2)=1$

$\Rightarrow |z| =1 $  represent a circle with centre at (0,0) and radius 1

Now how to use this in the given problem please guide further thanks.

Comment: just use the triangle inequality on $z^2 - 3z + 1$

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't learned the triangle inequality yet.

Answer (score 3):

By triangle inequality we have $$|z^2-3z+1|\leq|z^2|+3|z|+1=5$$

Comment: Is the traingle inequality $|\sum x_i|\le\sum|x_i|$?

Comment: how to move further from here, as if it could be $|z|^2$ I could have taken $ |z| =t$ and solve but here it is different viz. $|z^2|$

Comment: @sultan: $|z^2| = |z|^2$. You can see this by writing $z$ in polar form.